# How can we remove decimal number llike ".00" in PosTicket for "print receipt"?

Tags: python-3.6, odoo-11

I need to print receipt without decimal number in this receipt 
In PosTicket of POS odoo 11, the receipt always have decimal number. I can change the digit at product price outside, but when go to the Print Receipt. It have decimal number. How can i remove them to print without this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to take decimal number out through out the entire system?
or just the POS module? or particular form?

Odoo comes with built-in setting located at
***Settings>Technical>Database Structure>Decimal Accuracy***

From there, you can customize decimal points in the system, one of them is ***Product Price***.

Comment: yeah, i knew it, but my problem is in the PosTicket, if you change in settings, PosTicket not change at all